# What to do when too much butter added to my puff pastry dough?

Tags: butter, puff-pastry

I made puff pastry dough, but I figured I've added too much butter to it and now that it is in the oven, the butter has melted and covered the dough! (I need your advice for the next time) What should I have done to fix it? Does  adding flour make it better?

Comment: Don't panic yet. Puff pastry is supposed to contain boatloads of butter, and some does work its way out during baking. After it cools, update the question.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: It smells of butter, and tastes like a stick of butter! It's nothing but butter, If you ask me. :|

Comment: Did you make a traditional folded puff pastry, or a blitz pastry? If the former, adding flour won't help; just reduce the size of the butter block. If the latter, you may be able to adjust the ratios slightly.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this happen to me before. If it helps anyone else, I just took mine out and drained the butter from the tray and continued baking. I did it twice. I also had to bake them a little longer, like 10 minutes longer than the recipe called for until their color was just right and the tops nice and crispy. I had no hope but man... They were absolutely amazing. I made apple - feta hand pies.

Sidenote: i know for a fact that my oven doesn't get that hot, i need to get a thermometer for it. Secondly, I used more butter than called for. I didn't have a scale and I only had a giant 500g block so I had to eyeball my cut. So look out for those variables for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try slicing the butter more thinly and adding it in more layers. I use a handheld cheese slicer for a nice, thin cut. Alternatively, try freezing the butter and grating it, then sprinkling it on in a thin layer when instructed to apply it to the recipe.

Comment: The question is asking how to fix it if this has occurred. Your answer addresses how to prevent it from happening, not how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, she wroie that she needed advice for next time, so i figured she knew it couldn't be fixed now, and I answered on that basis. If I've misunderstood Gigili's post, my apologies.