# Would this cheat puff pastry really work?

Tags: puff-pastry

I watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYCIpX05INo) titled: "Cheats Quick Puff Pastry Recipe by Paul Hollywood". The one claims that it will result in the same dough and as flaky as the original puff pastry. The trick is, he used frozen grated butter instead of cubes of butter and used it twice in the rolling process. I would like to know if this really works, because then I don't have to wait for the butter to get softer so that flattens.

Comment: i think it should work as any kind of fat or shortening is acceptable. Puff pastry is just dough and fat usually butter

Comment: @JohnReese: Actually the same kind of fat is used, I am dubious because the grated butter is different from flattened cube of butter.

Comment: Once they have melted in the pastry, there should be no difference.

Comment: @Gigili i agress with James McLeod becuase here's the thing both forms of butter will be incorporated into the pastry anyway so same fat but different shape shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I've found Paul Hollywood's recipes and techniques are usually good, so I'd personally proceed on the assumption it works.

Comment: Butter normally gets soft as you start whacking it into shape. No need to wait for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that will work just like traditional methods. That's the real deal, it's not even a cheat, it's just smart.

BTW, the last line in your question raised my eyebrows. In puff pastry there is no waiting "for the butter to get softer so that it flattens". The butter is flattened (or sliced) with brute strength while the butter is still ice cold. That's critical to puff pastry. If the butter melts even a little before the layers are formed and it goes in the oven, you're sunk. The final product will be greasy and won't puff as much as it should. You get that puff by having very distinct layers of butter between layers of dough. If the butter is allowed to get warm, even a little, it will absorb into the flour.

Paul Hollywood's method is brilliant. It almost makes me want to make puff pastry from scratch. (almost)

For those disinclined to watch the video but still interested in puff pastry: What Mr Hollywood did in the video was grate frozen butter, then he kept the grated butter in the freezer until he had the rectangle of dough ready for the butter. Then he just sprinkled on the frozen butter and did the first envelope fold. He rolls that out into rectangle again, adds more frozen butter, and repeats the fold. Fridge for one hour, one more roll, fold, roll, done. Well! I wish I had thought of that.

**EDIT** 5 months later:

I'm still not particularly interested in making puff pastry from scratch since I doubt I can improve on the frozen stuff, however, I was encouraged by @rumtscho to try my hand at croissants. Since croissants are basically puff pastry with yeast, I decided to form my croissant dough using Mr Hollywood's technique.

It worked like a charm.

[image: 1]

Comment: Maybe this is why the OP found their pastry too greasy in [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45148/1672) - it does say "too much butter" but...

Comment: @Jefromi Yep. I hope she tries Mr Hollywood's suggestion. It's a very good solution.